# WebSphere Liberty profile logs

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am not able to find a log-file in WLP v8.5.5.1 showing request URL and request methods initiated by the clients. 
We have a bunch of REST-services (HTTPS) made by a consultant but in the `usr/servers/[apps]/logs` I don't find any request records (there is a bunch of log-files like `message.log, console.log, etc`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `message.log` is primary log file for WebSphere Liberty. If you want to log all http request you have to enable it, adding the following to the `server.xml` file

```
<httpAccessLogging id="accessLogging"/>
<httpEndpoint id="defaulHttpEndpoint" accessLoggingRef="accessLogging"/>
```

For more details and options check: [HTTP access log settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_http_accesslogs.html?lang=en)